# Как отключить блокировку экрана Android сразу после загрузки?

Tags: android

Есть приложение с автозапуском. Условно киоск. С презентацией. То есть ни кнопок, ни мышки, ни тача. Нужно, чтобы презентация стартовала при запуске. Старт приложения я сделал, но после загрузки появляется замочек, который нужно сдвинуть. Как его убрать?

Android 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, я уже сам нашёл.
Делается это через настройки -> безопасность -> блокировка экрана - None.